# How to reset index on pandas dataframe after unstack?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

After unstacking, filling na's, grouping and summing my dataframe I can't seem to understand what is going on with the index. the column I unstacked the rows on became a permanent index.

```
       **Month**    col_1     col_2   jan   feb  mar  ......
         **0**
         **1**
         **2**
```

when I go to reset the index this is what happens:

```
       **Month**       index  col_1     col_2   jan   feb  mar  ......
         **0**           0
         **1**           1
         **2**           2
```

I'm not understanding why I can't replace or drop Month and just have ONE regular, plain index on the far left?  It seems Month is also the only column in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is index name you can do

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

Or

```
df.index.name = None
```

Comment: df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1) worked.